# How can I get a list of all of the available print/fax drivers

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I get a list of all of the printer drivers and fax drivers from the OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I am not sure if it is the answer that you are looking for but you can get the name of all installed printers on the local machine with the following code:

```
foreach (String printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```